# Sectioning - Numbering

Tags: sectioning

I use the following commands

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\sffamily}
```

In order to split my book into sections. However, it shows the following

> 1 Section's Title

I want the form with point after the number

> 1. Section's Title

How can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `titlesec`: add to your preamble

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can redefine the section command using `\renewcommand`.     `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}` will put the dot directly after the section number. This however messes up the next lower level of sectioning. `\subsection{test}` would produce the following:

> 1..1 Test

Therefor you have also have to redefine the lower levels as show in the example below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsection}.}

\begin{document}
    \section{test}
    \subsection{test}
    \section{foobar}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Looks like you're using the `titlesec` package. In this case one would use something like this, to redefine the numbering:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\sffamily}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\Large\sffamily}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}
```

Comment: This messes up cross-references, which will also have the  final dot .